# Spark: How to modify the output directory of a local SparkSession?

Tags: apache-spark

I have the following `SparkSession` which I use for testing:

```
  SparkSession.builder().master("local").getOrCreate()
```

Whenever I run for example a unit test that writes data, e.g., `df.write.csv("foobar")` the output directory will be in the top-level of my project. I know I can modify the path argument to the writer, but I'm specifically interested in changing the root directory (both for reads and writes) globally, without having to specify it outside of the configuration.

Comment: What do you mean by root directory? Can you elaborate?

Comment: If my tests save or loads dataframes, it creates and loads directories in root directory of my project, i.e., where the src, test, build.sbt files are. In other words, `new File("./")`. I want these directories to be saved and loaded elsewhere.

Comment: AFAIK, I am not aware of any such config parameter.You must rely on the argument of the writer for writing data to your own path.

Comment: You have spark.local.dir -Directory to use for "scratch" space in Spark, including map output files and RDDs that get stored on disk. This should be on a fast, local disk in your system. It can also be a comma-separated list of multiple directories on different disks. NOTE: In Spark 1.0 and later this will be overridden by SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS (Standalone, Mesos) or LOCAL_DIRS (YARN) environment variables set by the cluster manager.

Comment: But, I do not think this will help you. I searched all the properties out of curiosity but did not find any such parameter.

Comment: I've tried spark.local.dir, but it didn't do what I want.

Comment: There is no such parameter.You can set the path only in the writer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much debugging I've figured it out. All it takes is setting `user.dir` system property.
For example: `System.setProperty("user.dir", "/tmp")`, and all your local tables and output files will be saved in `/tmp`.